# Too many columns in SharePoint List - InfoPath doesnt load

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, custom-list

I'm editing a SharePoint List with InfoPath, the problem is that I'm using more than **260 columns** so the SharePoint wont load (loading is really slow) in the InfoPath formular.

Is there any possibility to use more than **260 Columns** at one list or should I use another solution? Should I use an other Programm? If Yes any hints?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There limit for number of columns in a SharePoint list is not set with count of columns it has, instead the **limit has been set as size occupied by all the columns** in your list. Each column type has a size value in bytes, The sum of all column's size in a SharePoint list cannot exceed **8,000 bytes**.

For example, the Single line of text column type has been allocated **30 bytes** in the SQL Database, so as per the column limit you can use only 266 **Single line of text** columns in a list not more than that or you cannot add anymore fields to it.

Calculate the total bytes of all the columns in your list to find solution for your issue.

Refer [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary) for more details.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
I will list all the columns i use (including the protected ones):

 - 17 single line of text --> 510B 
 - 4 Look up --> 240B
 - 12 Choice --> 360B
 - 1 Counter --> 10B (i think it's "int")
 - 2 Person/Group --> 20B
 - 34       Yes/No --> 238B
 - 2 date/time --> 28B
 - 125 Number --> 1750B
 - 212 Currency    --> 2968B

all columns together are using 6124Bytes which is under the limit of 8000 Byte...
What could be the problem? Any other solutions?

Comment: @MSDN I read that "300 bytes are reserved, leaving 7700 bytes for end-user columns"